Remote Control Spectrum Analyzer / TCP Previous segment not captured
I am trying to remote control spectrum analyzer via c code.
There are no errors in code.
I had physical connection device and laptop. Then i run this code i receive these errors in wireshark;
enter image description here
i write c code and i was expecting to remote control spectrum analyzer.

Please post text as text, not as pictures of text. If there are no errors in your code then this isn't a programming question but a networking question and as such off-topic.
